# TextField's cursor works incorrectly in iOS. (works well in Android)

Tags: flutter, textfield

I got a problem with Flutter Textfield like below, could you please give me suggestion to fix it. I try to new project like below gif, but the same bug.

Thanks in advance.

### Steps to Reproduce

1. Type something to `TextField`
2. Move `Cursor` to beginning of this `textfield`.
3. Tap to end of text (to move `cursor` to end of text).
4. Click `backspace` in `keyboard` to delete text but can't delete anything, I try to input something but `cursor` move to beginning and insert character to beginning (It means I guess: `Cursor` is render in end of text, but it actually is in begin of text).

**Expected results: Cursor should be in end of text and user can delete text normally after step 3.**

**Actual results: Do step 4, and can not delete character normally in iOS. (Works well in Android)**

[image: Here is reproduce steps that I did record]

Answer (score 0):

From the code I see in the background of your image, the issue is that you're not providing a pre-initialized `TextEditingController` to the `TextField` so a new controller is being created for every call of the `build` method.

You should declare and instantiate a `TextEditingController` in `initState` that is passed to the `TextField` and disposed in `dispose`. This involves changing to a stateful widget if it is not already.

Follow the example in [the docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField-class.html).
Example from docs:

```
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  TextEditingController _controller;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = TextEditingController();
  }

  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: TextField(
          controller: _controller,
          onSubmitted: (String value) async {
            await showDialog<void>(
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return AlertDialog(
                  title: const Text('Thanks!'),
                  content: Text('You typed "$value".'),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    FlatButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                      child: const Text('OK'),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I did try your sample code but the same issue, I got issue in my project and try to create fresh project for demo, so I don't think that is the issue to cause bug. I think it can be bug in Flutter. If you have time, please try with you code above. I guess you will get the same error.

Comment: It's possible this is an issue with the iOS emulator or with your implementation of the example. Have you tried on a physical device?

Comment: I tried already. The first time I found this bug is in real device. Do you have any flutter app, could you try now in that app?

Comment: What was the result with the sample code? Could you show that? I have never seen this error when implementing it with the method shown in the docs.

Comment: Here is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14gCcDhnBvYLUCrYtIa16_Ss4edd_DWgZ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Taha & @iapicca, That issue is the bug of `Flutter` at version  `1.17.4 • channel stable`. It was fixed at dev channel `Flutter 1.20.0-2.0.pre • channel dev`.

I'm still waiting for when it is available in `stable channel`.

Ref: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60164#event-3491696982